# Help with c++ logic?

Tags: c++, logic

```
Something::methodname()
{  
    (unsigned char*) ptr = (unsigned char*) m_pptr;

    while ((*ptr || *(ptr+1)) && (((unsigned char*)m_pptr+BUFSIZE)<ptr))
        ptr++;

    if(ptr == m_pptr)
        return ptr; 

    return ptr + 1;
}
```

`m_pptr` is a protected member of a class. `ptr` is local to this function

Could someone help me with the logic of this code? I know it compiles but the answers I'm getting out are not the ones I'm expecting. I am memset-ing a buffer full of A5's and the while loop fails somehow. It skips right past it. Any help would be great.

This will go through a buffer and if the value of the pointer or the value of `(ptr+1)` is true it will increment the pointer AND the ptr can't exceed the size of the buffer(which is found by `m_pptr` "pointer to the beginning of the buffer" + buffer size) has to be true also. The if statement says if m_pptr(pointer to beginning of the buffer is the same as `ptr` then return just the pointer.

this function returns a `void*` and is passed nothing

Comment: I think you have a stray curly brace in there somewhere

Comment: You haven't actually said what you're expecting the code to do...

Comment: And I'm pretty sure it doesn't compile.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. Voting to close, as recommended [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94095/should-we-close-first-questions-when-they-are-of-poor-quality/94097#94097)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 (((unsigned char*)m_pptr+BUFSIZE)<ptr))
```

looks backward:

```
 (((unsigned char*)m_pptr+BUFSIZE)>ptr))
```

would be more likely; Even more sane:

```
while (ptr < ((unsigned char*) m_pptr + BUFSIZE)) // until end of buffer
{
    if (!*ptr)      // null char reached
        break;
    if (!*(ptr+1))  // null char almost reached
        break;

    // do stuff

    ptr++;
}
```

Comment: This is for a entry mechanism. someone enters text then null pointer. more text null pointer. etc etc until double null where there is no more entries available. The while loop checks to see if the value of the pointer true(any number but zero) or the value after it is true or (any number but zero) and the ptr can't be bigger than the buffer size

Answer (score 2):

This bit looks suspicious to me:

```
 while ((*ptr || *(ptr+1))
```

Imagine that ptr is pointing to a valid character byte, followed by a NUL terminator byte.

The first sub-test of the above line will evaluate to true, and so ptr gets incremented.  Now ptr is pointing at the NUL terminator byte, and *(ptr+1) is pointing at the byte AFTER the NUL terminator byte... which might be garbage/undefined, and therefore might be non-zero, at which point (ptr) will be incremented again (because the second sub-test evaluated to true this time), so that ptr now points to the byte AFTER the NUL terminator byte.  And from there on your pointer heads off into la-la-land, trying to interpret data that was never meant to be part of the string it was parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it look cleaner and simpler if you used for-loop instead?

```
for ( int i =0; i<BUFSIZE && (ptr[i] || ptr[i+1]); i++);
```

It would be easier to notice wrong comparison, wouldn't it?
And i think it would be also easier to see that in this case it should be

```
for ( int i =0; i<(BUFSIZE-1) && (ptr[i] || ptr[i+1]); i++);
```

or even

```
for ( int i =1; i<BUFSIZE && (ptr[i-1] || ptr[i]); i++);
```

unless obiviously you accounted for that by having BUFSIZE equal to buffer size minus one.